# How to test connection to incoming mail server with a certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, smtp, ssl-certificate, sha256

A customer of ours cannot receive email from our .NET web application because our server SMTP cannot connect to their inconing email server.
They told us our certificate might not be compatible with SHA256 standards. 
I am pretty sure they are wrong because our certificate is a new Rapid SSL which fully supports 256 bits cryptography, confirmed by the provider which sold it few months ago. And moreover our SMTP server, set up and running under IIS 6 in Windows Server 2012 R2, works fine with anyone else and any other .NET application we developed.

So, I would like to test the connection to their incoming mail server using the certificate by `openssl s_client` and check if I get some error messages. I would run `nslookup` to discover the IPs/the names of their email servers but then how can I test the connection with the certificate? Which is the correct command to launch?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: When you move to U&L.SE, please ping me. I'll take a look at it with you on the new site.

Comment: @jww: are you sure I can post on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange? Because my issues are related to Windows Server instead...